# Object.create with arguments

Tags: javascript, object, arguments, prototype

**Disclaimer:** I don't want to use constructors and I don't want to use the keyword `new`. I want to do this all with Object.create.

Here is the code I have, that works perfectly fine:

```
var vectorPrototype = {
    x: null,
    y: null
} 

var v1 = Object.create(vectorPrototype)    // line 6
v1.x = 1
v1.y = 1

console.log(v1);
// { x: 1, y: 1 }
```

What I would like to do, is create a new object and pass in x and y all in one line. Is this possible?

Comment: make a function that calls Object.create(), then the other stuff needed to the instance for a one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the properties parameter:

```
Object.create(vectorPrototype, { x: { value: 1 }, y: { value: 1 } })
```

Comment: This is good. I guess I am confused why I need to specify `value`. Is this some type of standardized way that this always is done?

Comment: yes,this how you define a default value. thats part of the properties you can give to`x` along with writable, configurable etc.. check this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my hat:

```
function Vector(x, y)  {
   var prototype = {
    x: null,
    y: null
  } ;
  var ret = Object.create(prototype);
  ret.x = x;
  ret.y = y;
  return ret;
}
```

This should work with `new` as well as without it. That said, I'm not sure if this classifies as "not a constructor" in your point of view.

Answer (score -1):

You can create object like this:

```
var v1 = {x:1, y:1};
```